# WPF Font renders thin based on zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, fonts

I'm working on a project to copy a user interface from a PDF render of an existing interface. The original uses the font "MS UI Gothic" at a 20pt size. In Visual Studio (2015, 2017, 2019) if you zoom in from 100% to 110% the font will display almost bold like in the PDF copy, but zooming to 100% the font will display thin. When running the application the font displays thin.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="MS UI Gothic 20 looks thin" FontFamily="MS UI Gothic" FontSize="20" />
<TextBlock Text="MS UI Gothic 21 looks bold or correct" FontFamily="MS UI Gothic" FontSize="21" />
```

Below is a test I built to show the problem. The image compression makes the font seem thicker at 20pt but you can still see the change from 21pt to 20pt, and how it is thin 
[image: WPF App showing bad rendering of MS UI Gothic]

I have tried some `TextOptions` that have been used by others to fix some font problems but they had no effect on this.

I may have to use 18 or 19 bold, but it seems like there is something else that should be able to be done to tell Windows to render the font correctly. Also looking at the Font Viewer in Windows they have the 18pt and larger size rendering correct, but have problems at 12pt. 
[image: Windows Font Viewer MS UI Gothic]

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried `UseLayoutRounding`?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I just checked and that had no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing and coming up with no way to change the way to tell WPF to render it correctly I came to the conclusion that I can decrease the font from 20px to 19px then apply a font weight. This causes the smaller font to render correct and not change sizing of layouts and things too much.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="MS UI Gothic 20 looks thin" FontFamily="MS UI Gothic" FontSize="20" />
<TextBlock Text="MS UI Gothic 19 SemiBold looks correct" FontFamily="MS UI Gothic" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="19" />
```

Below is a screenshot with the change.

[image: Using SemiBold with a 1pt smaller font looks correct]

I hope this helps some others, I also looked at using a [different font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gothic+A1), but that would add complexity having to include it with the application.